# why consumer thread is starting first?

Tags: java

```
package ProducerConsumer;

public class Queue {

    int item;
    boolean isEmpty=false;

    public int put(int item)
    {
        this.item=item;
        return this.item;
    }

    public int get()
    {
        return item;
    }

}

package ProducerConsumer;

public class Producer extends Thread{


    Queue q;
    public Producer(Queue q)
    {
        this.q=q;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        synchronized (q) {

            for(int i=1;i<=5;i++)
            {
                if(q.isEmpty==false)
                    try {
                        q.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                System.out.println("Producer produced = "+q.put(i));
                q.isEmpty=false;
                q.notify();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }


        }
    }

}
```

package ProducerConsumer;

```
public class Consumer extends Thread {

    Queue q;
    public Consumer(Queue q)
    {
        this.q=q;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        synchronized (q) {
            for(int i=1;i<=5;i++)
            {
                if(q.isEmpty==true)
                    try {
                        q.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    System.out.println("ITEM CONSUMED:"+q.get());
                    q.isEmpty=true;
                    q.notify();

            }
        }
    }

}
```

package ProducerConsumer;

```
public class MainApp {
    public static void main(String[] args)

    {
        Queue q=new Queue();

        Thread t1=new Thread(new Producer(q));
                //t1.setPriority(1);
        t1.start();

        Thread t2=new Thread(new Consumer(q));
        t2.start();



    }
}
```

This is my output:

```
ITEM CONSUMED:0
Producer produced = 1
ITEM CONSUMED:1
Producer produced = 2
ITEM CONSUMED:2
Producer produced = 3
ITEM CONSUMED:3
Producer produced = 4
ITEM CONSUMED:4
Producer produced = 5
```

Question is: why my consumer thread is running first ? I tried setting the priority for my Producer thread also. Its not working.
Also, if there is any other flaw in the code or design flaw in code, please do mention.

Comment: You need to learn how to write thread-safe code.  Good luck.

Comment: this http://goo.gl/qTdHxJ tutorial helped a lot with these problems

Comment: Hey Guys, i found the problem... I should initialize my boolean variable to TRUE. Now it runs Fine :) 

Producer produced = 1
ITEM CONSUMED:1
Producer produced = 2
ITEM CONSUMED:2
Producer produced = 3
ITEM CONSUMED:3
Producer produced = 4
ITEM CONSUMED:4
Producer produced = 5
ITEM CONSUMED:5

Thanks for help :)

Comment: Your producer DOES NOT need to check if the queue is empty, the ONLY thing that you producer may need to know is when the queue is FULL, if it can be full...  
Yet another point - with correct implementation of the queue you don't need to synchronise your producer if it is going to be a single producer) at all as it will be always adding at the tail of the queue and your consumer(s) will always be getting data from the head of the queue

Answer (score 1):

```
synchronized (q) {
```

You told all of your  threads to never run at the same time.
That defeats the purpose of threads.

Comment: Ofcourse. i told all my threads to not run at same time. 
when my consumer Thread starts, it checks Queue isEmpty(which it true).

Answer (score 0):

Parallel execution of threads implies that they can run in any order. If you want them to run in predefined order, you have to explicitly program so. The order of thread's start is not a mean to set thread's execution order.